# Compile an array by including quantity without using JQuery

Tags: javascript

I was working on an application that needs to have the ability to compile by quantity and decompile back into a large list. Here is some psuedo code for what I am struggling to create in Javascript.

Psuedo Code:

```
var array = [lorem, lorem, lorem, doler, doler, sit];
var orginizedArray = [];
var unorginizedArray = [];

function compileArray(orgianal, result){
    //code
}

compileArray(array, orginizedArray);

console.log(organizedArray);

function decompileArray(original, result){
    //code
}

decompileArray(orginizedArray, unorginizedArray);

console.log(unorginizedArray);
```

Console Log:

```
[4 lorem, 2 doler, 1 sit]
[lorem, lorem, lorem, doler, doler, sit]
```

Thank you all so much who can help me figure this out as I hit a huge roadblock trying to solve this.

Comment: What is your question? What is your code even supposed to do? And what do you mean by *"compile an array"*??

Comment: compile or combine ??

Comment: @UnholySheep. The question is how do I make the pseudo code into real Javascript code. The pseudo code also explains what exactly is going on and what it needs to do.

Comment: No, the pseudo code does not explain anything. You have an array, feed it into a function an get something out - that's a black box, not a description of what you need. Pseudocode would show what those functions are supposed to do, what the algorithm is, etc. . Also you are essentially asking for code, as you have not shown what you have tried doing to solve this issue yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)  function can group an array like this.

```
var array = ["l", "l", "l", "d", "d", "s"];
var filtered = array.reduce(function(accumulator,current){
  for(var i = 0; i < accumulator.length; i++){
   if(accumulator[i].val == current) {
     accumulator[i].count++; 
     return accumulator;}
  }
  accumulator[i] = {count:1, val:current};
  return accumulator;
}, []);
// filtered == [{count:3, val:"l"},{count:2, val:"d"},{count:1, val:"s"}]
```

You can loop through this array to 'decompile' the array back into its parts

```
array = [];
filtered.forEach(function(group) {
  for(var i = 1; i <= group.count; i++)
  {
    array.push(group.val);
  }
});
// array == ["l", "l", "l", "d", "d", "s"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = ['lorem', 'lorem', 'lorem', 'doler', 'doler', 'sit'];
   var organizedArray = [];
   function compileArray()
   {
       var currentNum = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       {
           currentNum++;
           if (array[i] == array[i + 1])
           {
               continue;
           }
           else
           {
               organizedArray.push(currentNum + ' ' + array[i]);
               currentNum = 0;
           }
       }
   }
   compileArray();
   console.log(organizedArray);
```